# Ubuntu Apache wsgi web.py 404 not found

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi, web.py

web.py 'Hello, world' example gives a 404 error on Apache on Ubuntu 14.04: "The requested URL /api/ was not found on this server."

I followed these instructions: http://webpy.org/cookbook/mod_wsgi-apache-ubuntu

Apache 000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html

  WSGIScriptAlias /api /var/www/html/webpy-app/code.py
  AddType text/html .py

  ...

  <Directory /var/www/html>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride FileInfo
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
      AddHandler mod_python .py
      PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
      PythonDebug On
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

code.py that gives a 404 error:

```
import web

 urls = (
     '/.*', 'hello',
     )

 class hello:
     def GET(self):
         return "Hello, world."

 application = web.application(urls, globals()).wsgifunc()
```

wsgi is working, e.g. the if I put the following into code.py, it works (taken from http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#embedded-or-daemon-mode):

```
import sys

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = u'wsgi.multithread = %s' % repr(environ['wsgi.multithread'])

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output.encode('UTF-8')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah - fixed by adding:

```
<Files code.py>
    SetHandler wsgi-script
    Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
</Files>
```

to Apache 000-default.conf, which I found on http://webpy.org/install#apache

Comment: Get rid of mod_python. You shouldn't be using it and it will interfere with normal operation of mod_wsgi, which is why you needed to add that.